# There should be a way of seeing how many people favorited a question (Android app)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

There should be a way of seeing how many people favorited a question in the Stack Exchange Android app.

Hopefully the developers can add this feature.

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps it depends on the frequency of usage in android app. when the users mostly access it from android app, I'm sure that the developer will complete all features.

Comment: You can see the number of favorites questions have on the website but you cannot on the Android app, so it has nothing to do with the privacy.

Comment: does it really not exist in android app? Then I misunderstand (sorry for my english)

Comment: to those confused about my comment on this answer -- the answer was edited.